# Axis cameras wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, vapix

Trying to integrate with axis camera to manage events and actions as described here http://www.axis.com/files/manuals/vapix_event_action_51386_en_1307.pdf

While generating service from [wsdl](http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/event1/EventService.wsdl) provided in docs have stub instead of service. After quick review of wsdl found out that no service definition provided. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it by adding service definition to **wsdl** file like this:

```
    <wsdl:service name="EventClient"> 
        <wsdl:port name="Event" binding="aev:EventBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://YOUR_CAMERA_IP/vapix/services"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```

And the service was generated.